# How to get the file extension in Jeysey?

Tags: java, jersey

In Jersey, I define a resource like this:

```
    @GET @Path("/{id}")
    @Produces({ APIMediaType.IMAGE_PNG, APIMediaType.IMAGE_JPEG, APIMediaType.IMAGE_GIF})
```

I get request like `/123.png`, `/abc.jpeg`.

How can I get the `png` or `jpeg`?

Comment: What do you mean "get it?" What exactly do you want to get, and where?

Comment: I want to get `png` or `jpeg` (depending if the request was `http://example.com/resource/id.png` or `http://example.com/resource/id.jpeg`) in a resource handler.

Comment: Is it removed??

Comment: Not in the URL bar of my browser but I wonder how to get it programmatically from the request.

Comment: Is it not included in the `{id}` parameter? if not, Inject `@Context UriInfo` as a method argument, and get it from the URI.

Comment: Ok thanks, I will check later